# Not in oracle subquery returning 0 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

This is returning 0 records.

```
         SELECT
               p.phone_nbr                             AS phone_nbr,
               p.caller_id                             AS caller_id
          FROM phonebook p
          WHERE     p.identification = '123456789'
          AND p.phone_nbr NOT IN (SELECT s.phone_nbr
                                  FROM status s
                                  WHERE p.phone_nbr = s.phone_nbr
                                  AND s.blocked = 'Y'
                                  AND s.phone_nbr IS NOT NULL);
```

However, if I remove the subquery records or if I run just the subquery then records are returned. Also if I hardcode the results of the subquery into the NOT IN like `NOT IN ('9403459384', '800230493')`, results are returned.

So i'm at a loss for why it's not returning anything. I've added the "is not null" to make sure no null phone numbers are getting selected but that didn't fix the issue.

Edit: Is it because there's no shared primary key constraint / unique between the two tables?

Comment: My guess was the same as The Imapler wrote. Since according to your comments this doesn't solve your issue, could you setup a fiddle that illustrates the problem?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without sample data (which will require *your* debugging first to prepare test case), because the subquery looks ok (except invalid table alias). It may be some extra characters in the value, capital O instead of zero etc. Please post reproduce example for we were able to analyze the issue with real data

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for the same data for your tables; an English description (not code) of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for the sample data.

Comment: Your query appears to work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TkZbXXCa)

Comment: For debugging you may join two datasets (possibly cross join) and use `dump(value, 16)` on two columns to compare their byte content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without the sample data,  but you have a bit confusing sintax in your subquery. You are selecting from status table aliased as "s" and you use table name in Select clause but not in the Where clause - there is an alias used.
This might be causing the problem, not for sure, though. You could avoid the confusion if you left join your subquery to the main one and filter the result (using where clause) to just rows not matched.
Something like here (you should adjust it to your actual context):

```sql
Select
        p.phone_nbr     AS phone_nbr,
        p.caller_id     AS caller_id
From        
        phonebook p
Left Join   
        (   Select  phone_nbr
            From    status 
        ) s ON(s.phone_nbr = p.phone_nbr And s.blocked = 'Y' And s.phone_nbr IS NOT NULL)
Where 
        p.identification = '123456789' And s.phone_nbr Is Null;
```

Answer (score 2):

The subquery produces nulls and your query is not dealing with them correctly. The SQL Standard defines trivalent boolean logic (true, false, unknown) and you are dealing with the third case without knowing it.

Also, you need to understand well what "null" means in relational databases. A null means that **the value does exist but, it's just missing**. The `NOT IN` operator is particularly tricky on this. For example `3 NOT IN (1, 2, 4, null)` evaluates to `unknown` since it's not possible to find out if the last element *could be* 3; since a `WHERE` predicate (unlike constraints) requires the predicate to evaluate only to `true`, the rows are discarded.

The easiest way of avoiding to deal with this fine grained trivalent logic, is to use `NOT EXISTS (<subquery>)` instead; `NOT EXISTS` is straightforward to understand.

For example, your query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT
  p.phone_nbr AS phone_nbr,
  p.caller_id AS caller_id
FROM phonebook p
WHERE p.identification = '123456789'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM status s
    WHERE s.phone_nbr = p.phone_nbr
      AND s.blocked = 'Y'
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, even when using NOT EXISTS, I am getting 0 rows back. I have tried setting blocked to 'N' in NOT EXISTS but also getting 0 rows. The only thing that allows me to get rows back is if I set it as AND EXISTS

Comment: I'm also finding that if I add another constraint like s.location = p.location, results get returned? But not the results I want. I don't understand why adding another constraint would get me results

Comment: A subquery has `... AND s.phone_nbr IS NOT NULL` which excludes the described situation

Answer (score 0):

```
The note written is not clear cause you have written that you are running the subquery independently and the records were displayed 
In the below query it will not be compiled - as if i just run the subquery then sql compiler will fail the query asking for p.phone_nbr

AND p.phone_nbr NOT IN (SELECT s.phone_nbr
                                  FROM status s
                                  WHERE p.phone_nbr = s.phone_nbr
                                  AND s.blocked = 'Y'
                                  AND s.phone_nbr IS NOT NULL);

To answer your question - the query will work with below rewriting
 SELECT
               p.phone_nbr                             AS phone_nbr,
               p.caller_id                             AS caller_id
          FROM phonebook p
          WHERE     p.identification = '123456789'
          AND p.phone_nbr NOT IN (SELECT s.phone_nbr
                                  FROM status s
                                  WHERE 
                                  s.blocked = 'Y'
                                  AND s.phone_nbr IS NOT NULL);
```